# How can I set Caffe output feature to int?

Tags: python, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, caffe

I'm doing inference with caffe

Some of the results after going through the conv1 layer.

```
'''
 [[ 0.         0.         0.        ...  0.         0.         0.       ]
  [ 2.4921875  8.1796875  8.125     ...  8.15625    8.15625    8.15625  ]
  [ 2.4921875  8.15625    8.125     ...  8.15625    8.15625    8.15625  ]
  ...
  [ 7.96875   14.4296875  0.        ...  0.        12.953125   0.6171875]
  [ 0.         0.         1.9140625 ... 19.6875     0.         0.       ]
  [ 1.2109375  0.         0.        ...  0.         0.        19.71875  ]]
...
```

I want to use these as inputs to the next layer without the decimal point.

like this

```
'''
 [[ 0  0  0     ...  0    0    0  ]
  [ 2  8  8     ...  8    8    8  ]
  [ 2  8  8     ...  8    8    8  ]
  ...
  [ 7   14  0   ...  0    12   0  ]
  [ 0   0   1   ... 19    0    0  ]
  [ 1   0   0   ...  0    0   19  ]]
...
```

Is this possible?

Comment: can you add some part of your code also ?

Comment: You can do rounding (e.g. using a "Python" layer) but then you'll loose your gradients. Are you working on quantized nets?

Comment: @Shai thanks for your comment  i'm working on mobilenet quantized by my self i want some more quantizing. I'm trying to figure out the python layer by hints at your comment. thank you

Comment: As @Shai suggested, you may use a port of Caffe that supports integer quantization - or use Python round to get the output from each layer and feed it explicitly to the next layer.